# How to Convert Detected Object to COCO dataset Json

Tags: json, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I follow Object Detection Demo in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb:

```
# Actual detection.
output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
```

But I want to convert output_dict (output from function run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)) to COCO annotation JSON type so I can input it to make benchmark between different Object Detection models.

Here is code to benchmark model: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocoEvalDemo.ipynb

```
#initialize COCO detections api
resFile='%s/results/%s_%s_fake%s100_results.json'
resFile = resFile%(dataDir, prefix, dataType, annType)
cocoDt=cocoGt.loadRes(resFile)
```

But you need to input a COCO Json type.

Are there anyone can tell me how to Convert from output_dict to COCO Json?

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. Have you ever made it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. The last code snippet:

https://lijiancheng0614.github.io/2017/08/22/2017_08_22_TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API/